# Optaplanner - Optimization problem - Error: Queue Full - ArrayBlockingQueue

Tags: java, optaplanner

I'm using Optaplanner for some optimization problem and in the last days there is this error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full at java.base/java.util.AbstractQueue.add(AbstractQueue.java:98) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.add(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:329) at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.decideNextStep(MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.java:157) at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:72) at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:83) at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:193)`

Does anyone have an idea when this error occurs in Optaplanner? From my perspective Optaplanner adds moves (possible Solutions to the Optimization problem) to this operationQueue to be evaluated by the Operating Threads. It seems, that they're not fast enough with the evaluation.

The error occurs for "bad" optimization problems with less data, where it's hard to find a good solution.

Comment: This should of been impossible (emphasis on should of); The queue has size (# move threads + selectedMoveBufferSize, where selectedMoveBufferSize is the maximum number of move evaluations at any given time). Before any move evaluations are made, each move thread need to take the current Setup/ApplyStep operation (of which there will be # move threads in the queue). No new MoveEvaluationOperations are added to the queue until they are all consumed (for reproducibility). Before a step is ended, the operation queue is cleared, and either # move threads ApplyStep or Destroy operations are added.

Comment: What was your SolverConfig, domain and constraints?